# How do I detect the type of file being uploaded?

Tags: node.js, format

I need to be able to upload files, but they have to be videos and images only. I know I can change the html input access but that doesn't provide any security as to what the user will upload. So I need to detect the type of the file uploaded and if it doesn't match my expectations, notify the user. My question is how do I do this? Is there a module for it? I've been googling this thing for the past 3 hours and I couldn't come up with something! Can you please help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: I've used [mmmagic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmmagic) to do this for audio uploads.

Comment: Does it work with video and image formats? (png/jpg and mp4 etc.)

Comment: As far as I know, yeah. It's for determining content types.